# How to properly calculate the QuickXorHash value

Tags: onedrive

I am trying to create a tool that will verify files uploaded to OneDrive for Business using the QuickXorHash algorithm they provided an example for here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/code-snippets/quickxorhash

The issue I am running into is that the resulting hash value I get using their code does not match the hash result from the OneDrive returned json file when comparing the exact same file.

Since Microsoft provided no documentation on how to use the sample code, I have to make assumptions, so I could be using it incorrectly.  Does anyone have any insight into this?

Comment: how is you tools status? I am looking for a tool to compare the file on OD business and local storage.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  The problem was in the way I was converting the hashed byte array to a string. The code that I found online originally for this was the following:

```
int i;
StringBuilder outPut = new StringBuilder(byteArray.Length);
for (i = 0; i < byteArray.Length; i++)
{
     outPut.Append(byteArray[i].ToString("x2"));
}
 return outPut.ToString();
```

But, after doing some more research, I came across the correct way to convert the array, and this is even simpler:

```
return Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
```

This results in the string representation of the hash value matching what is on OneDrive.