# Creating QuickXorHash from fileBytes then comparing to Sharepoint hash

Tags: c#, sharepoint, hash, checksum, xor

I'm attempting to compare the hash of a file on the server to the one just uploaded to sharepoint prior to deleting.

[MS Docs about QuickXor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/code-snippets/quickxorhash?view=odsp-graph-online)

I use the code from MS docs above, and have read a couple other SO articles.

I was making the mistake in the article below, but after correcting I'm still not getting the expected result.

[Very Similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47650931/how-to-compute-onedrive-xorhash-in-c-sharp)

```
    public static byte[] CalculateQuickXorHash(byte[] theFileBytes)
    {
        using (var hash = new QuickXorHash())
        {
            return hash.ComputeHash(theFileBytes);
        }
    }
```

From the call:

byte[] hash = FileStorageHelper.CalculateQuickXorHash(theFileBytes);
byte[] sharepointHash = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jObject["file"]["hashes"]["quickXorHash"].ToString());

```
 if (hash == sharepointHash)....
```

The hash I'm getting from from sharepoint is 28bytes, the hash computed locally is only 20 bytes.

[image: Hash Inspected]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49437101/how-to-properly-calculate-the-quickxorhash-value Seems the issue was using a byte array not a 64 bit string

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue was using a byte array not a 64 bit string –